# If $x_0$ is a real root of $p(x)=x^4+a_3 x^3 + a_2 x^2 +a_1 x + a_0$ and $p'(x_0) \ne 0$. Does $p(x)$ have at least two real roots?

Tags: calculus, polynomials

> If $x_0$ is a real root of $p(x)=x^4+a_3 x^3 + a_2 x^2 +a_1 x + a_0$ and $p'(x_0) \ne 0$. Does $p(x)$ have at least two real roots?

I don't know what would be a good way to solve this. Any tips?

Edit: I'm in calculus 1 and this should my answer should probably not assume things about things from algebra about roots of polynomials.

Comment: $p(x)$ always has an even number of strictly imaginary roots, and hence always has an even number of real roots. Hence, if there is one real root, there better be two, regardless of the derivative condition. (Assuming that $a_i$ are real. If they are not, this does not apply).

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг In my course (calculus 1) we have not been shown that so I would need to prove it

Comment: Since nobody mentioned it so far, just for the sake of completeness: This statement is only true, if the coefficients $ a_i $ are real. But I guess, this should be the case for your problem.

Comment: @m.g. Yes that is the case in my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $\lim_{x\to\infty}p(x)=\lim_{x\to-\infty}p(x)=\infty$. If $p(x)$ crosses $x$-axis once it must do it at least twice.

Comment: Nice and simple I like it!

Comment: This argument is lacking. There could be a global minimum at $x_0$, you have to prove there's not.

Comment: @GabrielRomon there can be no extremum at $x_0$ since $p'(x_0)\neq 0$ by assumption.

Answer (score 4):

Since $x_0$ is a root of $p$ with $p'(x_0)\neq 0$, it has multiplicity $1$. Thus $p(x)=(x-x_0)q(x)$ where $q$ has degree $3$ and $x_0$ is not one of its root.

Since $q$ has degree $3$ it has a real root $x_1\neq x_0$, and you're done.

Comment: I'm not sure what multiplicity 1 means, but I understand the rest of the proof. Also I said $p'(x_0)\ne0$ but I'm not sure how this affects this solution.

Comment: $p'(x_0)\neq 0 \implies$ $x_0$ is not a root $q$. That's the crux of the proof.

Comment: Can you explain why $x_0$ is not a root of $q$? I notices I don't really understand why not.

Comment: I understand now acutally, but how does p′(x0)≠0 mean that the multiplicty is 1?

Comment: $x_0$ has multiplicity $k$ iff $p(x_0)=p'(x_0)=\ldots=p^{(k-1)}(x_0)=0$ and $p^{(k)}(x_0)\neq 0$

Comment: I see, cool answer, I don't think I would be allowed to use it since we have not learned that, but still nice!

Comment: @Jason, you can prove it easily in this simple case. Just write $p'(x) = q(x) + (x-x_0)q'(x) \implies p'(x_0) = q(x_0)$. Since $p'(x_0)$ is not $0$, $q(x_0)$ is not $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Complex roots are always complex conjugate pairs. Now since your polynomial is of degree 4, this means that it should have four roots. Since there are 3 remaining unknown roots ($x_0$ given to be real) there is only room for one pair should there be one therefore one of the other three roots must be real also. The condition $p'(x_0)\neq 0$ also rules out the possibility of the other root being equal to $x_0$ since the curve would not be tangent to the $x$-axis

Answer (score 1):

There is several ways, for example:

- As $(x-x_0)$ divides $p$ you have:
  $$p(X)=(X-x_0) Q(X)$$
  where $Q$ is a polynomial of degree $3$. But any polynomial of degree $3$ as a real root and $x_0$ is not a root of $Q$.
- As $p(x_0)=0$ and $p'(x_0)=0$ you know that the sign of $p$ change near $x_0$. Without loss of generality we can suppose that for some $\epsilon >0$, $p(x)< 0$ for $x \in (x_0-\epsilon,x_0)$.
  So $p(x_0-\epsilon)<0$ but $\lim_{x \to - \infty} p(x)=+\infty$. So as $p$ is continuous there exists $x_1 \in (-\infty,x_0-\epsilon)$ such that $p(x_1)=0$.

Comment: My question states that $p'(x_0)\ne0$ how does this affect the second solution?

Comment: If $p'(x_0) = 0$ then you can not know if the sign of $p$ changes near $x_0$. For example $(x-x_0)^2$ and $(x-x_0)^3$ both cancel for $x=x_0$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rather elementary proof. If $ z=a+bi \in \mathbb{C} $ we denote the complex conjugate by $ \overline{z} = a - bi $. We denote the roots of $ p(x) $ by $ x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3 $ where $ x_0 \in \mathbb{R} $ and $ x_i $ are the other zeros - possibly complex.

Now you can check for yourself that for any two complex numbers the following holds:
\begin{align*}
\overline{z_1 \cdot z_2} = \overline{z_1} \cdot \overline{z_2} \\
\overline{z_1 + z_2} = \overline{z_1} + \overline{z_2}
\end{align*}
This means that for any complex number $ z $ we have
\begin{align*}
\overline{p(z)} = \overline{z^4 + a_3z^3 + a_2z^2 +a_1z+a_0} = \overline{z}^4 + a_3 \overline{z}^3 + a_2\overline{z}^2 + a_1\overline{z} +a_0 = p(\overline{z})
\end{align*}
This implies that whenever we have any root $ z_0 $ of $ p $, then $ \overline{z_0} $ is also a root of $ p $. Hence complex roots come in pairs.

Now we can deduce your desired statement. If any of $ x_1, x_2, x_3 $ is real, we're done (because $ x_0 $ is a single root). If wlog $ x_3 $ is complex, so is wlog $ x_2 $. Now $ x_1 $ cannot be complex, because otherwise $ x_0 $ would also be comlex. Hence $ x_1 $ must be real. Since $ p'(x_0) \neq 0 $, $ x_0 $ must be a single root, in particular $ x_1 \neq x_0 $ is another real root of $ p $.